# ¿Es posible responder a una pregunta con dos opciones negando una de ellas?

Tags: preguntas, palabras-interrogativas

Dada la pregunta:

> –¿Compro té o café?

¿Es posible responderla con lo siguiente?

> –No té

¿O la forma correcta (y única) de responder es esta?

> –Café.

Comment: Qué pregunta tan interesante. Desde una mente lógica tiene todo el sentido: *¿P o Q?* respondo *no Q*, ergo claramente *P*.

Answer (score 7):

Sólo podrías usar:

> No té (una versión reducida de: "No compres té")

si inmediatamente después agregas:

> ... sino café.

La forma "No té, sino café" se usa para enfatizar: "No A sino B".

Lo que sí podrías decir en forma aislada es:

> Té, no.

En este caso estás dejando en claro que no quieres té, pero no queda claro si quieres café u otra infusión.

Comment: De acuerdo y bien explicado.  Nomás agrego otra opción: *No quiero té.*  (Pero nótese que las normas culturales generalmente no permiten una respuesta tan corta.  Típicamente la cortesía exige más, por ejemplo: *El té no se me antoja ahorita, gracias, pero un cafecito sería genial, si no es mucha molestia, doña Fulana.*  O *El té no nos hace falta, pero sí, ¿traes un paquete de café, por favor?*)

Comment: Fue en una conversacion telefónica informal. Como ud. comenta dije: "Té, no".  Al final, no me escucharon el "no" y trajeron té.  Luego argumentaron que no es correcto, gramaticalmente, responder así.  Yo pienso que es posible responder de las dos formas, aunque es cierto q la forma ideal es: " Café". ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: @Gila Gramaticalmente es correcto en español anteponer el objeto directo para causar énfasis, como también es correcto usar "no" en lugar de la frase verbal completa "no compres". Por lo tanto, si es correcto decir: *Té, no compres*, también lo es decir: *Té, no*.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: No me convence el uso de la coma en "Té, no". He publicado una pregunta al respecto, por si le quieres echar un ojo. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23528/t%C3%A9-no-o-t%C3%A9-no

Comment: La coma marca la ruptura del orden sintáctico normal.