# ¿"Té, no" o "Té no"?

Tags: puntuación

Basado en esta respuesta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23497/14936

En el siguiente contexto:

> -¿Compro té o café?
>   -Té, no.

Queriéndose decir que no se compre té (es decir, que compre café) no me convence el hecho de que la respuesta lleve coma.

Por lo que la pregunta es:
**¿Es correcto el uso de la coma? y si es así, ¿de que tipo de coma se trata?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La coma que reemplaza al verbo se llama "coma elíptica". No es éste el caso, pues "compres" no aparecería en el lugar exacto donde está la coma, sino después de "no". No decimos:

- *Té compres no.

sino

- Té, no compres.

Observemos que el uso de la coma persiste aun cuando está presente el verbo.

Se trata, entonces, de una coma que algunos llaman "hiperbática", puesto que es indicativa de la alteración del orden sintáctico considerado normal.

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_(puntuaci%C3%B3n)) dice:

> Otro uso es conocido como **coma elíptica**, que es aquella que se utiliza para sustituir el verbo en los casos en que se omite porque ya se mencionó anteriormente o se sobreentiende.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> - *Pamela es libre; Patricia, también.* (La coma sustituye a es.)
> - *Víctor es delgado; Pamela, alta.* (La coma sustituye a es.)
> - *Marcelo perdió su billetera; Juan, su mochila; Ricardo, la cámara.* (La coma sustituye a "perdió".)
>
> La coma también se utiliza cuando se invierte el orden lógico de los complementos de la oración (**coma hiperbática**). Por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> Con esta nevada, no llegaremos nunca.
> ```

Con respecto al punto 1.2.10. del DPD (gracias, walen, por tu aporte), observamos que:

a)  La prescindencia de la coma puede ser por brevedad del complemento circunstancial (“té” es complemento directo, por lo que no aplica la supresión de la coma en este caso).

b)  Los casos de complementos directos (CD) enfáticos presentados van seguidos directamente por el verbo: *Vergüenza debería darte*.

El único caso parecido al que nos compete (por haber un “no” detrás del CD), donde se dice que la coma es opcional, es:

•   Carne(,) no suelo comer mucha.

Si equiparamos este ejemplo al de OP, obtenemos:

- ¿Comes carne o verdura?
- Carne(,) no.

En el caso que nos ocupa, me parece que, además de la presencia de “no”, el imperativo vuelve más deseable la coma, puesto que la oración enunciativa: “Carne no como” fluye mejor que “Té no compres”. Mi impresión es que la posición inicial habitual del imperativo vuelve más extraño el CD antepuesto, y eso hace que se haga necesaria una pausa y, por ende, que sea conveniente una coma.

De todos modos, ante las dudas de Brian (ver comentarios), he hecho la siguiente consulta a elcastellano.org (volveré cuando tenga una respuesta):

Encontré esta pregunta y respuesta en la Web:

Coma antes del adverbio de negación no

P: ¿Es preceptivo colocar una coma antes del adverbio de negación no cuando este finaliza la oración? Por ejemplo: "el 30 % de la gente lo cree necesario y el 70% no". Muchas gracias.

R: La coma tiene entre otros usos el de reemplazar a un verbo ya nombrado anteriormente para no repetirlo, por ejemplo: Yo traeré las bebidas y el pan para la fiesta y María, la carne y las ensaladas. La coma reemplaza a traerá: Yo traeré las bebidas y el pan para la fiesta y María traerá la carne y las ensaladas. El ejemplo de su consulta se entiende de esta manera: El 30% de la gente lo cree necesario y el 70% de la gente no lo cree necesario. En este caso no se coloca la coma, puesto que esta no se requiere para reemplazar al verbo, aquí solo se está truncando la oración: El 30% de la gente lo cree necesario y el 70% no.

Ahora bien, mi pregunta es la siguiente: cuando,  además de la elisión del verbo, hay alteración del orden sintáctico, ¿corresponde o no la coma antes de no? Supongamos que alguien pregunta: ¿Compro té o café? Y se responde: Té, no. Mi entendimiento es que la coma es correcta. Inclusive visualmente "Té no" me resulta chocante. Sólo puedo imaginar "no" detrás del complemento directo en eslógans como: Paz sí, guerra no. Me gustaría conocer su opinión. Gracias.

Comment: @walen Para mí la coma es correcta y a lo sumo opcional. El artículo habla de conveniencia o no de usarla en algunos casos. Sólo aceptaría un "no" o un "sí" inmediatamente después de un OD por ejemplo en un slogan de campaña: "Amor sí, odio no."

Comment: Creo que deberías profundizar más en la coma hiperbática, ya que ahora mismo la respuesta está argumentando a favor de algo que tu mismo has dicho no es la respuesta correcta, con una nota al final sobre la respuesta correcta.

Comment: Yo no he dicho que no sea correcta. Pero más tarde ampliaré.